# All Hardware do not respond except mouse

Tags: 20.04, lts, ubuntu-studio

Ubuntu startup and works correctly but after a while it suddenly stop responding any more

Only the mouse is responding for movement but not clicks

No keyboard or menus, **I only end with just a moving mouse cursor** and nothing else

Letting the device for a while don't solve anything

I'm forced to unplug power cable and restart device every time

> More occasionally when browsing internet or using VSCode, but not limited to that

> Windows on the same machine never did that, and using windows is not an option

**I need to know the problem and stop it**

---

some helping info

```
----- >>> lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

----- >>> inxi -Fx
System:    Host: xxxxx Kernel: 5.4.0-96-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Compaq Elite 8300 MT v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 3397 serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: K01 v02.90 
           date: 07/16/2013 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-3470 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: avx lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 25541 
           Speed: 3008 MHz min/max: 1600/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3008 2: 2461 3: 2233 4: 2705 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] driver: nvidia v: 340.108 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2 v: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.108 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-96-lowlatency 
Network:   Device-1: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: f040 
           bus ID: 00:19.0 
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
           IF-ID-1: dbr_static state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
           IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
           IF-ID-3: vetha603db9 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
           IF-ID-4: vetheee87ca state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 530.92 GiB used: 50.64 GiB (9.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD3200AAJS-00L7A0 size: 298.09 GiB temp: 27 C 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST3250318AS size: 232.83 GiB temp: 23 C 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:1f.2 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 54.75 GiB used: 30.41 GiB (55.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 20.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 26 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 267 Uptime: 56m Memory: 7.72 GiB used: 2.05 GiB (26.6%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: zsh v: 5.8 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: It may happen when all the RAM is used up and the system switches to swap. How much RAM do you have? Check if moving to a distribution with a lighter desktop environment, like Kubuntu or Xubuntu or Lubuntu partially solves the problem. Try to change your work habits (do not open the web browser and VS Code simultaneously), and if possible, upgrade the RAM.

Comment: 8 GB - I will edit with `inxi -Fx` output

Comment: It never did so on a 4 GB Ram device, and widows is running correctly side by side with ubuntu... need to stop that crash

Comment: In that case, the NVidia driver may be the issue. Can you try changing the driver in the "Additional drivers" tab in software sources, and check if that helps?

Comment: I will convert to X Server option now and see but that show take time to test then I'll back for you, thanks for your advice

Comment: Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi this did the trick and fixed many things in resolution and display, could you please put it as answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Done. Please edit my answer with the information about which driver worked best for you, and which one was faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more then enough system resources to run Ubuntu. This issue is most likely due to a faulty driver of the graphics card.

Open software sources and go to the additional drivers tab.

Several drivers for the graphics card should be available. Choose one of them and restart the computer. Use it for some time and check it performance. Repeat, until you find the best driver.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.