# how to extend gpu and cpu from physical drive like swapfile

Tags: graphics, ram, swap, cpu, gpu

> starting from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1229795/966305

I have a machine running ubuntu lts

whenever I run any program that is GPU comsumer like chrome or blender everything stops working {I mean mouse and keyboard and even display don't move}

this happend before but for all programs - and was solved by switching to open source graphic driver of NVidia and that was this question [All Hardware do not respond except mouse](https://askubuntu.com/q/1389545/966305) - now only this two programs do that especially blender

I put a cpu graph applet in my panel and found that every time my device hangs the cpu is got to it's maximum usage

ofcourse blender uses GPU more than CPU and chrome do that when using webGL or many javascript excutions

```
>> inxi -G;                                                                                                      
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVA8 v: 3.3 Mesa 21.2.6
```

---

I have a solution in my mind
-- like `swapfile` is used for sitiuation where ram is overcame by any program

if something is used like a swapfile for gpu that would be helpful

**the questions is how ?**

Comment: The GPU is already an extension to the CPU to make graphics tasks faster -- sounds like you either are not using the GPU, need a better driver (proprietary drivers are usually better than open source ones), or need a bigger/faster GPU.  Desktops make a new GPU easy to replace, laptops can do this via an external GPU through a Thunderbolt expansion box or an expresscard adapter (to allow a desktop GPU to be used.  See https://egpu.io/forums

Comment: yes but for now I can't change either cpu or gpu, I just want the device not to crach untel I change it all but this would take time - and you don't learn new things all the time - also I'm afraid that even blender 2.7 do the same when rendering, so it may be also another problem with blender itself so invistigating in a new device is very risky for now - however it should be done later - could the cpu or gpu virtualized or extended by storage, that would help for now

Comment: `sounds like you either are not using the GPU` @ubfan1 what do you mean and how I test against that - I'm sure it's loaded and available to system - but what about usage - is there a missing configuration before using GPU on ubuntu ?

Comment: There are ways to run a program on a GPU (prime, bumblebee,...?) but I don't use them. What driver loads up at boot determines which GPU is generally used.  See nvidia-smi output for a listing of programs using the GPU.  Your 210 is so old I'm surprised blender works at all.  Your "crash" may be simply running so slowly you don't notice the difference. The only software solution I can think of is to rent a cloud emulation with a bigger GPU and run your program there.

Comment: Today I found a helpful use of cpulimit [ https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-with-cpulimit-on-ubuntu-linux ] but that don't work with viewport shading or rendering now the gpu functions is the only problem, if I can't extend it I may go for your solution or provide my tasks as models with no texturies :), but I think there is a solution